# Git (bitbucket) merge a previous commit to master

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge

I have a develop branch (say at commit c) which is many commits ahead of master (say at commit a). But I forgot to push my production code (say at commit b) to master or to a separate branch.

Is it possible to push/merge my production code (i.e an earlier commit in develop branch) into master?

```
a (master branch)

a           b                   c (develop branch)
            (Need this commit               
            merged to master)
```

Edit: I don't want all the commits from develop merged/pushed to master, which is easy. I just want code up to a previous commit (not the last commit) to be merged to master. I have this code in a test server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for your problem is simply to merge everything up to the commit b into master.

In your case the following command should to what you want to do:

```sh
git checkout develop
git rebase master # Always suggested to avoid unneeded merge c onflicts
git checkout master
git merge <commit-id of b>
```

The small script below allows you to create a kind of a sandbox to play a little bit around with this scenario

```sh
mkdir sandbox
cd sandbox
git init
touch a.txt
git add a.txt
git commit -m "Added a.txt" a.txt
git checkout -b develop
touch b.txt
git add b.txt
git commit -m "Added b.txt" b.txt
touch c.txt
git add c.txt
git commit -m "Added c.txt" c.txt
git rebase master
git checkout master
```

Comment: This worked. I did not do git rebase master. Did `git checkout develop`, `git checkout master` and `git merge <commit Id>` worked. Thank you.

Comment: yes, you just needed a merge in the end. That part about commit c is white noise.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert a commit between `a` and `c` without changing `c`. Since you already pushed `c`, somebody could have use it to start their work, my suggestion is to avoid rebasing `b` in between.

That being said, your best alternative is probably to push `b` to a new branch, then `git merge c` onto b, so that you now have the following, then merge to master.

```
  d    <-- merge devel into new branch
 /|
| b    <-- new branch
| |
c |    <-- develop HEAD
| /
a      <-- master HEAD
```

Once you are here, merge onto master, or back onto develop. It's ugly, but avoids disrupting anybody's work.

**EDIT**

If you don't want `c` merged into master, but only `b`, the situation is different. Scenario A: you want to keep branch `develop` as in gitflow develop. Then you'll need to (on develop):

git reset --hard 
git add .
git commit -m "rolling back c"
git push

This will add a new commit after `c` that is an identical copy of `a`. Remember, we DON'T want to destroy other people lives.

Then, `git push` commit b onto develop. How? Probably you have some uncommitted changes. Make sure to `git stash` those for a moment, while working on `develop`, rollback `c` then `git stash pop`, solve any conflicts and create the new commit `b`

Your develop will now look like:

```
a -> c -> a(rollback) -> b
```

Comment: How do I push b into a deffierent branch? I have b in a test server. Also, I dont want c in master. I just need b.

Comment: @Justin if that is the case, I got your question completely wrong. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the situation you are describing is the following :

```
a--*--*--*--b--*--*--*--c
^           ^           ^
master      |           |
            |           develop
            |
 (not marked by a branch, but this is the commit in production)
```

simply move master forward to b :

```
# one the many ways to do this :
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only b
```

The `--ff-only` is not mandatory, you will just be 100% sure that :

- either going from `master` to `b` is indeed a "fast forward" operation,
- or nothing happens, and you will have to look at the history of `master` and `b` to determine what you should do